# Unmerging all Cells in Many Workbooks in Certain Folder Path

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Here is the code am using but unfortunately its not working
am using excel 365 and windows 10
it gets stuck on excel interface with no errors showing and no action or processing and no file is open
Please help me find a solution or provide me with a ready made Excel VBA macro for doing the same task as I a use an old erp that exports its reports into htm then i convert them into excel and then have to merge all cells in order to work with them efficiently.

```
Sub UnmergeAllCellsinWorkbooksinOneFolder()
Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
Dim MyFiles() As String, Fnum As Long
Dim mybook As Workbook
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim ErrorYes As Boolean

'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
MyPath = "F:\Sales Rates"

'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    MyPath = MyPath & "\"
End If

'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xlsx*")
If FilesInPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
Fnum = 0
Do While FilesInPath <> ""
    Fnum = Fnum + 1
    ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
    MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
    FilesInPath = Dir()
Loop

'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
If Fnum > 0 Then
    For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
        Set mybook = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not mybook Is Nothing Then


            'Change cell value(s) in one worksheet in mybook
            On Error Resume Next
            With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                sh.Cells.MergeCells = False
            End With


            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                ErrorYes = True
                Err.Clear
                'Close mybook without saving
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            Else
                'Save and close mybook
                mybook.Close savechanges:=True
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            'Not possible to open the workbook
            ErrorYes = True
        End If

    Next Fnum
End If

If ErrorYes = True Then
    MsgBox "There are problems in one or more files, possible problem:" _
         & vbNewLine & "protected workbook/sheet or a sheet/range that not exist"
End If

'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sh is nothing. I think it should be fixed as below.

```
        With mybook.Worksheets(1)
            'sh.Cells.MergeCells = False
            .Cells.MergeCells = False
        End With
```

Comment: sh here is referenced to worksheet but i will try this fix as each workbook has only one sheet